# Native JPA queries not working when using Kotlin nullable type because of bytea casting error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using `Kotlin`, `Spring Boot` and `Spring Data` with `Hibernate` and `Postgresql`.

We created a repository class which extends `JpaRepository` and just found out that native queries are not working if nullable parameter is provided.

In this example, `isInternal` parameter can be true, false or null if we don't know that information yet (same as in our database).

```
    @Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT * FROM story WHERE is_internal = :isInternal",
        countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM story WHERE is_internal = :isInternal"
    )
    fun findEmployeeStories(
        @Param("isInternal") isInternal: Boolean?,
        pageable: Pageable
    ): Page<StoryEntity>
```

This query results in:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

If we try to add explicit casting, error changes.

```
    @Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT * FROM story WHERE is_internal = CAST(:isInternal AS boolean)",
        countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM story WHERE is_internal = CAST(:isInternal AS boolean)"
    )
    fun findEmployeeStories(
        @Param("isInternal") isInternal: Boolean?,
        pageable: Pageable
    ): Page<StoryEntity>
```

This query results in:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to boolean
```

If we change `@Param("isInternal") isInternal: Boolean?` to `@Param("isInternal") isInternal: Boolean` (to forbid nullable values) it works fine but we don't want that.

Above is just a simple example to reproduce the issue. Our query is complex that's why we tried to switch to native query instead of using JQL (where there where no such problems).

Thanks